# Combine Join query with Where condition query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've two sql queries as below, 2 queries working alone fine.

1.

```
SELECT * FROM
products
WHERE isLive IS FALSE AND
timeClose IS NULL AND
( timeOpen is NULL OR timeOpen <= 1 )
ORDER BY timeOpen ASC
LIMIT 11;
```

2. 

```
SELECT t1.* , GROUP_CONCAT('[','name:',t2.fileName,',','id:', t2.id,']') AS gallery
FROM products AS t1
JOIN gallery AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.productId
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

I tried below but have error

> Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1
> of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'data_base.t1.id'; this
> is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by,

```
SELECT * FROM (
    
    SELECT t1.* , GROUP_CONCAT('[','name:',t2.fileName,',','id:', t2.id,']') AS gallery
    FROM products AS t1
    JOIN gallery AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.productId
) as t1
WHERE t1.isLive IS FALSE AND
t1.timeClose IS NULL AND
( t1.timeOpen is NULL OR t1.timeOpen <= 1 )
ORDER BY t1.timeOpen ASC
LIMIT 11
```

[image]

Please help me to find out the solution.. Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the group by in the subquery

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, Yes thank you. Working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested

```
Error Code: 1140. In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'data_base.t1.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by,
```

add `GROUP BY t1.id` to the subquery, which you missed from

```
SELECT t1.* , GROUP_CONCAT('[','name:',t2.fileName,',','id:', t2.id,']') AS gallery
FROM products AS t1
JOIN gallery AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.productId
**GROUP BY t1.id**;
```